# Google Drive for teamwork and quota problem

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing, google-drive-shared-folder

I purchased a 200Gb. subscription plan for Google Drive, with the idea that we could use it to share files in an event we are organising. The problem is that many of the people who upload files to our Drive only have the free version (with its 15 Gb. quota)... and when they start uploading files, they eat at *their* quota instead of our 200Gb.

I've been searching and this seems to be how Google Drive was designed, but it's a big problem for our use case. Google's "family plan" (or however they call it) allows only 5 people to form part of a group and share drive space, and this is too few for us. Are there any other solutions, Google products, workarounds...?

Comment: Ask people to transfer the file ownership to your account. Another option is to use a Google Form for the request participants to deliver/drop/submit the files. They will use the quota of the form creator. Another option is to use a Shared Drive⛳but this require a Google Workspace account that includes this service. Etc, Etc.

Comment: Regarding transferring file ownership this only works for Google Docs Editor file formats.

Comment: @Rubén: none of those solutions are as flexible as we need. Plus, I've been looking into Google Workspace, but if I'm not mistaken, it requires you to pay for each user, and even so each one only has 30Gb. or so. We are a rather loose team, with a core group of people and some external collaborators who neverthless need access to upload and download files. Is there really no flexible solution for this in today's market?

Comment: I'm sorry. While there might be some overlaps, questions here should be about a practical, detailed problem about **using** a web application, not about finding / developing a solution meeting specific requirements. If you expect a solution that meets a specific set of requirements, consider asking your question on [softwarerecs.se].